# Replace Spaces and Format Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

New to xslt so please pardon me if the question is not well formed.

So I have to export data from our application, now for doing that I wrote XML code and while exporting certain fields need to be formatted for which i am using XSLT. Now the issue here is in my SQL SERVER database I have a contact number field, some of the number are in the format 1234567890 while some have spaces 123 456 7890. So now when I am using the below mentioned xslt code, everything is working as expected if the field has spaces but messes up when it does not have spaces.
I know I can make changes in the database directly but that will not be  permanent solution. If anyone could provide some guidance it would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('(',substring(D_PHONE,1,3),') ',substring(D_PHONE,4,3),'-',substring(D_PHONE,7,4))" />
```

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 - not both.

Comment: Are you quite sure all the contact numbers are 10-digit US phone numbers? Because you wouldn't want to format them this way if any of the numbers are non-US.

Comment: All the 10 digit numbers are either canadian or US.. @MichaelKay - I would certainly love to hear more if you have a recommendation for enhancements . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a result of:

```
(123) 456-7890
```

you could do:

```
<xsl:variable name="phone" select="translate(D_PHONE, ' ', '')" />  
<xsl:value-of select="concat('(', substring($phone, 1, 3), ') ', substring($phone, 4, 3), '-', substring($phone, 7, 4))" />
```

or (a little more clearly):

```
<xsl:variable name="phone" select="translate(D_PHONE, ' ', '')" />  
<xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($phone, 1, 3)" />
<xsl:text>) </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($phone, 4, 3)" />
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($phone, 7, 4)" />
```

Comment: Sir Michael,
I apologize. It was a setting to be changed from my side. Your answer worked as expected sir. I apologize I should have checked before replying back.

Comment: Sir If you dont mind me asking. Sir can you please advise the best source to learn xslt and xml further? I am fairly good in XML but little unsure about xslt. And advise would be priceless. thank you sir

Comment: I am afraid I am not the right person to answer that.